# XSL Setting up an Index with Umlaut and removing definite article

Tags: xml, xslt, tex

As I mentioned in a previous question, I need to set up an XSLT from T.E.I to XeLaTex. One problem I was not able to solve is how to handle Umlauts and the definite article "the". Say I want to put "The beauty queen" into the index, in German it would be "Die Schönheitskönigin". 
The desired output starts off with the sort order and then writes what is shown in the index:

```
\index{Schoenheitskoenigin@Die Schönheitskönigin}
```

So German Umlauts should be replaced with "ae", "oe", "ue", "ß" with "ss" and the articles "der", "die", "das" should be removed from the sorting part.

I use XSLT 2.0 and have a lookup to get the index-entry. With the solutions provided below this is producing the correct output:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:param name="persons" select="document('person.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="person-lookup" match="row" use="number"/>

<xsl:template match="persName">
<xsl:variable name="s1" select="key('person-lookup', @key, $persons)/name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>\index{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace($s1,'ä','ae'), 'ö', 'oe'), 'ü', 'ue'), 'ß', 'ss'), 'Ä', 'Ae'), 'Ü', 'Ue'), 'Ö', 'Oe')'^(Die |Der |Das )', '')"/>
             <xsl:text>@</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$1"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where the person.xml is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <number>A01</number>
        <name>Die Schönheitskönigin Ilse</name>
    </row>
</root>
```

And the main.xml being something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persName key="A01>Ilse</persName> hatte einen schlechten Tag.
```

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained and minimized to the current problem.

Comment: You present code and say it is "now functioning", so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: What I wanted to say is: working as desired. The question was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove leading definitive articles from the input, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($input, '^(Die |Der |Das )', '')" />
```

Use the `replace()` function for the umlaut characters, too.

Comment: Couldn't `replace($input, '^(Die |Der |Das )', '')` solve the removal of the articles as well? Why do you suggest to use `analyze-string` for one task and `replace` for the other?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, of course, that's much simpler. Don't know why it didn't occur to me.